# PJSIP error code

Tags: error-handling, pjsip

Does anyone know in which case pj_sock_recv returns error code 120107 (0x1d52b)? I`m using`pj_sock_recv`function and it should return PJ_SUCCESS if packet is received, but in`__android_log_print` I get error code from that function.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be in system error space, thus it would be code 107, thus it would be ENOTCONN, socket not connected.